# Purity of Memoized Functions in D

Tags: caching, persistence, d, memoization, purely-functional

Are there any clever ways of preserving purity when memoizing functions in D?

I want this when caching SHA1-calculations of large datasets kept in RAM.

Comment: In what sense do you want the function to be pure? Why do you need this? -- Usually, the requirement is the other way around; A function should be pure to allow memoization.

Comment: @MarkusJarderot Yes, a function would need to be `pure` in order to be memoized, but if you memoize a function, then you can't use that memoized result from inside another `pure` function, because storing the result for memoization requires breaking purity. So, I assume that Nordlöw is trying to use memoization from inside of a `pure` function and that that's where he's running into trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** Pick memoization or purity. Don't try and have both.

**Long answer:** I don't see how it would be possible to preserve purity with memoization unless you used casts to lie to the compiler and claim that a function is `pure` when it isn't, because in order to memoize, you have to store the arguments and the result, which breaks purity, since the number one guarantee of `pure` functions is that they don't access mutable global or static variables (which is the only way that you'd be able to memoize anything).

So, if you did something like

```
alias pure nothrow Foo function() FuncType;
auto result = (cast(FuncType)&theFunc)();
```

then you can treat `theFunc` as if it were `pure` when it isn't, but then it's up to you to ensure that the function acts `pure` from the outside - including dealing with the fact that the compiler thinks that it can change the mutability of the return type of a strongly `pure` function which returns a mutable type. For instance, this code will compile just fine

```
char[] makeString(size_t len) pure
{
    return new char[](len);
}

void main()
{
    char[] a = makeString(5);
    const(char)[] b = makeString(5);
    const(char[]) c = makeString(5);
    immutable(char)[] d = makeString(5);
    immutable(char[]) e = makeString(5);
}
```

even though the return type is always mutable. And that's because the compiler knows that `makeString` is strongly `pure` and returns a value which could not have been passed to it  - so, it's guaranteed to be a new value every time - and therefore changing changing the mutability of the return type to `const` or `immutable` doesn't violate the type system.

If you were to do something inside of `makeString` that involved casting a function to `pure` when it violated the guarantee that `makeString` always returned a new value, then you'd have broken the type system, and you'd be risking having very buggy code depending on what you did with the values returned from `makeString`.

The only way that I'm aware of getting purity when you don't have it is to cast a function pointer so that it's `pure`, but if you do that, then you *must* fully understand what guarantees a `pure` function makes and what the compiler thinks that it can do with it so that you fully mimic that behavior. That's easier if you're returning `immutable` data or a value type, because then you don't have the issue of the compiler changing the mutability of the return type, but it's still very tricky business.

So, if you're thinking about casting something to `pure`, think again. Yes, it's possible to do some stuff that way that you couldn't otherwise, but it's very risky. Personally, I'd advise that you decide whether purity matters more to you or memoization matters more to you and that you drop the other. Anything else is highly risky.

Comment: Wouldn't everything be fine if the function-internal memoization table is thread-local and I, of course, get the memoization logic correct?

Comment: @Nordlöw Whether it's in TLS or not has nothing to do with purity. Sure, if it's not, then you're opening yourself up to more problems when you do something like cast the function to pure, but the problem is that you're forced to cast the function to pure to do the memoization, and that is opening up a huge can of worms. If you do that, you have to do it in a way that perfectly mimics what the type system requires for pure and doesn't violate any of its guarantees or mess up any of its optimizations. That requires that you be very knowledgeable and very careful. I'd advise against even trying.

Answer (score 0):

What D allows to express within the type system is an impure function that memoizes a pure one.

Conceptually the memoizer is also pure, but the type system is not sufficiently expressive to allow that. You'd need to cheat somewhere.